# Search Display Templates - How to display hover panel on click rather than on hover

Tags: search, search-results, display-template

I'd like to customize my Display Template so that the Hover Panel appears only when a user clicks on an item in the search result.  The default behavior is the hover panel appears when a user mouse's over the item in the search result.
Thanks!

Comment: You are asking for how to disable the Hover Panel and adding a link that will open a dialog similar to the Hover Panel? Remember that the click on item is reserved for opening the item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image] Hi Martin,

I have achieve your requirement , please change Event `onmouseover="_#= ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_"` to `onclick="_#= ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_"` in your Search Display Template.

Comment: I did exactly that.  It worked perfectly.  Thank you.